# What does "ima" mean in "ima sue the s*** out of em"?

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation, informal-language, accent

Is "ima" an informal spelling of "I must"?

> MegaCharizardZord  Replying to @nytimes about COVID-19 vaccine:
> i just hope when i take it don't die lol.  i trust the government in Canada, but if I do get something **ima sue the shit out of em** lol.

> Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Sierra_Iola/status/1336217313046110210)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "ima" spoken or only written? How casual is it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2894/is-ima-spoken-or-only-written-how-casual-is-it)

Comment: See also the discussions on EL&U: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/531170/does-the-a-of-ima-extend-to-other-pronouns/531195#531195, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130911/what-exactly-is-imma/130936#130936

Answer (score 82, accepted):

*Ima* is an informal contraction of *I'm going to* when it's used in [***going-to future*** construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going-to_future) - not in sentences like *I'm going to London* etc. It's also written [*i'ma* or *imma*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/i%27ma) in informal conversations.

How did *I'm going to* come to be pronounced/spelt that way?

In casual speech, we tend to drop consonants that require more effort to articulate, assimilate nearby consonants, drop weak vowels etc., for the [ease of articulation](https://www.britannica.com/topic/ease-of-articulation-principle). Grammatical words that don't have any meaning on their own (*function words*?) like *have to, going to (not present continuous), has, is, was, will* etc., are highly susceptible to these sound changes. For instance, *have to* is often pronounced *hafta*, *trying to* is pronounced *tryna*, *want to* is *wanna* etc etc. The same thing happened to the phrase *I'm going to*.

There are a few processes involved in the reduction of *I'm going to* to *ima*.

- **I'm going to → I'm gonna:** the consonant *t* is often dropped in many other clusters and grammatical constructions as well (as in *tryna, wanna* etc). Here it's dropped and the vowel of *to*—which is usually a schwa [ə]—is linked with the preceding word; going to → gonna: [ˈɡəʊɪ̃ŋtə] → [ˈgə̃nə]
- **Deletion of the /g/:** plosives (/g t d k/ etc) require great effort to articulate (the air is completely blocked and then released), so people dropped the plosive /g/ to make its articulation easier: [aɪ̃m gə̃nə] → [aɪ̃m ə̃nə] (*i'm ana*)
- **linking *I'm* and *gonna***: In causal and connected speech, consonants and vowels are often linked by a process called [liaison](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)), so both *I'm* and *gonna* join together and become [aɪ̃mə̃nə] (*i'mana*).
- **Syncope of the vowel in the second syllable:** Unstressed schwas are often lost through [syncope](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266364/106592) (for example, 'choc**o**late' is *choc.late* for most speakers). If we removed the schwa from the second syllable, we'd get [aɪmnə] (*i'mna*).
- **Deletion of /n/:** It's simple cluster reduction. In English, two nasals that are next to each other are often reduced to a single nasal (as in *dam**n***), so the /n/ is deleted, yielding in this case [aɪ̃mə] (i'ma). Or people dropped the /n/ for the sake of ease.

Some people further reduce the diphthong [aɪ] it to something like [a], which results in [ãmə] (*ama*)

That's why people spell it that way. It's highly informal and as TypeIA pointed out in a comment, it's mostly a verbal thing and is not usually found in written form. It's commonly found in chatspeak or [lolspeak](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lolspeak). You shouldn't write it in any kind of writing...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117136/discussion-on-answer-by-void-what-does-ima-mean-in-ima-sue-the-s-out-of-em).

Comment: re: ...shouldn't write it in any kind of writing - maybe with the exception of depicting how a character speaks in a novel, for example?

Comment: @ParibusCeteris: Probably :P

Answer (score 2):

Note that we observe two different evolution paths from (i'mana): in some places it went towards (i'mna), dropping the middle vowel, but other places dropped the final vowel instead, becoming (i'mawn) or more precisely (ah'mawn).

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Do you have any sources for this assertion? We usually require people to back their answers up with sources and citations.

Comment: @nick012000 Just to play devil's advocate here: do you have this same complaint of the currently-accepted answer, which also has no citations for its claimed etymology?

Comment: Sources or not, this is still not an answer. It seems to be additional context on a different answer and should be converted to one.

Comment: @nick012000 I don't think the other answer needs more citations. I don't think this answer needs more citations, either. That's... kind of my whole point. It needs something, but links ain't it. I can't crystallize what I think it is that it needs, though, and I think you may be in the same boat; but if not, how about suggesting an edit that adds a link to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drop#English), sense 20, and calling it a day? (It will then have about twice as many citations per word as the answer you defend!)

Comment: @DanielWagner: "*but none corroborating the proposed etymology*" **Re:** That's a very good point, but have you read the question and my answer? The questioner is merely asking about the meaning of *ima* not etymology. And my answer does answer that question. The information I added is general and extra. The answer is really just a single line, though I hate single line answers so I explained how we tend to speak.

Comment: @DanielWagner - This answer was authored by a new contributor who may not know much about how SE prefers corroborative references in an answer. I think nick's comment was meant to be helpful.